# How to trim white space in StringBuffer in JAVA

Tags: java, string, reverse, tostring, stringbuffer

I was trying to reverse the String using pre-defined method reverse() which is available in StringBuffer 
I took input from the user and while printing the reverse string I used toString() method to avoid an extra space

```
import java.util.*;

public class Small {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
    int num;

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    num = sc.nextInt();

    while(num>0)
    {
       String t;

           t=sc.nextLine();

       StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(t);

        sb.reverse();

       System.out.println(sb.toString());

     num--;  
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
   2
   hello
   welcome
```

Output:

```
<Empty line>
olleh
```

Can anyone please advise why this blank space is coming and also not getting second output?

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. You have no need for the synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

`sc.nextInt()` doesn't consume the newline at the end of the line containing the number.

Add `sc.nextLine();` after it:

```
num = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```